# Custom function inside controller not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.8, laravel-controller

I created a `controller` with `resource`. I made a custom function inside it however when I use it as a `route` in my `blade.php` it says that it is not defined.

Any help with the error and explanation about it is highly appreciated!!

**Blade**

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="issueModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="{{route('inventory.deduct')}}" method="post">


        </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**custom function inside controller**

```
public function deduct(Type $var = null)
{
    dd("test");
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::resource('inventory', 'InventoryController');
```

Comment: How did you created the routes?

Comment: Oh wait I'll add my routes @TharakaDilshan

Comment: I added it @TharakaDilshan please see edit

Comment: See. the resource routes only adds those particular routes only. If you defined any custom method. you need to add another custom route. thats it.

Answer (score 3):

```
Route::post('/inventory/deduct', 'InventoryController@deduct')->name('inventory.deduct');
```

Add this to your Routes in Web.php file.
Resource only creates the default routes for controller, not the custom ones.

Comment: So having a route made with default resources, it doesn't affect having custom ones inside it?

Comment: @kwestionable No, it doesn't. Whatever custom routes you make, you need to add them to your `routes/web.php` file.

Comment: So regarding the `inventory@deduct` does it point to my `InventoryController`? Or do I have to make another customer controller?

Comment: @AhmadKarimi I think it should be `InventoryController@deduct`

Comment: @TharakaDilshan, you are right. I rectified the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Resource route is for `index`, `create`, `store`, `show`, `edit`, `update` and `destroy`. Your new route is not defined in a resource route. So you have to create a new route to use it. Add this route above your resource route in `web.php` file

```
Route::post('inventory/deduct', 'InventoryController@deduct')->name('inventory.deduct');
```

This will make your route and you can use it in your form and you can make the function to your controller to do what you want to do.